# How to get more attention to a post without bounty option?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

I have posted the following question(s) in the following thread:
[Prediction of continuous variable - CV, Overfitting, Choosing K principal components](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/259362/technical-theoretical-help-prediction-of-continuous-variable-modeling-proble)

And it got only 17 views, when about half of them is me, refreshing the page :)

I'm new in this specific stackexchange community, thus i don't enough reputation to offer a bounty, for example, in order to draw more attention to the question, as i'm used to in stackoverflow.

Is there any other way to get the post more attention?

On the "looks" side - Maybe it's not enough elaborated? Maybe something in my formatting is missing or incorrect?

On the "tools" side - Is it allowed to post a comment for bumping the post? (I'm guessing not, and don't want to break any community rules by doing so)
Is there any other option available to get more attention to my post?

Comment: have a look [here](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4477/my-questions-dont-get-an-answer-is-it-a-general-trend-or-am-i-doing-somethin) - I think the answers that were given to me, as well as the answers to other questions I was referred to, may be of interest to you.

Comment: @DeltaIV is right. I would try to summarize by saying that if a question perhaps is being ignored because it is not clear or not engaging, then by far the best idea is to try to improve it.  If a question is at best going to appeal to, or be intelligible by, a very small number of people, nothing much will change that. (I'd add that trivial edits to bump a question to the top are forgiveable just about once ($\pm 1$).)

Comment: Is there enough detail? Is it precise or concise enough? Is it carefully written with attention to English language, typesetting, formatting of code or data? Is there a graph that would catch attention?  (Note that these criteria can conflict.)

Comment: As a technical note, refreshing the page from the same IP address on the same day does not count towards page views, so you likely aren't responsible for half of the existing views. W/ only 17 views, it isn't surprising you aren't getting many responses (no one can w/o viewing it 1st), so you need to attract some views. From the outside, the only thing people can see is the title & the tags. Your title is vague at best. Assuming it is tagged correctly, you could work on giving it a usefully descriptive title. But realize that you many not get an answer right away no matter what.